# CallEvent::isCalled() alternative if a function is called by pointer

Tags: clang, clang-static-analyzer

I am trying to write a checker to catch potential handle leaks (it's on Windows: i.e. a handle should be closed by `CloseHandle`).

So `checkPreCall()` checks if `CloseHandle` is called.

`Call.isCalled()` works great except one case when `CloseHandle` is called by pointer. It happens because of using a template class that takes a pointer of closing function as a template parameter (useful to close different types of handles by appropriate functions: `FindClose`, `CloseHandle` etc.).

`Call.dump()` prints "&CloseHandle(this->m_h)" in this case, so clang understands correctly that this a pointer and that this is a pointer of `CloseHandle`. But how in the code I could "extract" the identifier of a function called by pointer?

Comment: [Here is a link](https://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/cfe-dev/2018-May/057842.html) to the related [cfe-dev] mail list discussion for any future readers.